# Como saber o que está gerando este erro por este log?

Tags: android

Criei  um Navigation Drawer seguindo um exemplo, mas eu gostaria de saber o por que desse erro, tem como saber pelo log?

http://pastebin.com/RAf5Eswz

```
10-27 10:50:26.045: W/Trace(18420): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-27 10:50:26.195: D/libEGL(18420): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
10-27 10:50:26.200: D/libEGL(18420): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
10-27 10:50:26.200: D/libEGL(18420): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): Device driver API match
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): Device driver API version: 17
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): User space API version: 17
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013
10-27 10:50:26.220: D/OpenGLRenderer(18420): Enabling debug mode 0
10-27 10:50:28.140: D/AndroidRuntime(18420): Shutting down VM
10-27 10:50:28.140: W/dalvikvm(18420): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c1e930)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial/com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Sharing Fuel from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0013
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Sharing Fuel from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0013
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1997)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:207)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome$1.<init>(Welcome.java:94)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:95)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    ... 11 more
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Sharing Fuel
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:429)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1989)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    ... 18 more
10-27 10:50:29.710: I/Process(18420): Sending signal. PID: 18420 SIG: 9
10-27 10:50:26.045: W/Trace(18420): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-27 10:50:26.195: D/libEGL(18420): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
10-27 10:50:26.200: D/libEGL(18420): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
10-27 10:50:26.200: D/libEGL(18420): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): Device driver API match
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): Device driver API version: 17
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): User space API version: 17
10-27 10:50:26.205: E/(18420): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013
10-27 10:50:26.220: D/OpenGLRenderer(18420): Enabling debug mode 0
10-27 10:50:28.140: D/AndroidRuntime(18420): Shutting down VM
10-27 10:50:28.140: W/dalvikvm(18420): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c1e930)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial/com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Sharing Fuel from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0013
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Sharing Fuel from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0013
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1997)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:207)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome$1.<init>(Welcome.java:94)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:95)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    ... 11 more
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Sharing Fuel
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:429)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1989)
10-27 10:50:28.150: E/AndroidRuntime(18420):    ... 18 more
10-27 10:50:29.710: I/Process(18420): Sending signal. PID: 18420 SIG: 9
```

[image: Imagem a partir da linha 94]

Activity Welcome.java

```
package com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import br.isckosta.sharingfuel.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import br.isckosta.sharingfuel.model.NavDrawerItem;
import br.isckosta.sharingfuel.slidingmenu.AddNewPostFragment;
import br.isckosta.sharingfuel.slidingmenu.FeedFragment;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class Welcome extends Activity {

    // Declare Variable
    Button logout;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItem;

    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Carrega os titulos do menu

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // Carrega os icones do drawer nas resources

        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItem = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // Adicionando itens do Nav Drawer para o Array

        // Feed
        navDrawerItem.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1), true, "22"));

        // Adicionar novo Post
        navDrawerItem.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));

        // Recycled typed array

        navMenuIcons.recycle();
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // Configurando o adapter list para o nav drawer

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            displayView(0);
        }

        /**
         * Slide menu item click listener
         * */

        // Sessão de recuperação de usuário do Parse

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        // String struser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();

        // TextView txtuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtuser);

        // txtuser.setText("You are logged in as " + struser);
        //
        // logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

        logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Logout current user
                ParseUser.logOut();
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            displayView(position);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {

        // Atualizar o conteudo do substituindo os fragments

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            fragment = new FeedFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new AddNewPostFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {

            Log.e("Welcome", "Error in creating fragment");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {

        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

---

> 10-27 12:07:41.710: E/(28528): Device driver API match 10-27
>   12:07:41.710: E/(28528): Device driver API version: 17 10-27
>   12:07:41.710: E/(28528): User space API version: 17  10-27
>   12:07:41.710: E/(28528): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1
>   BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013  10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial/com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:134)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  ... 11 more 10-27
>   12:07:41.710: E/(28528): Device driver API match 10-27 12:07:41.710:
>   E/(28528): Device driver API version: 17 10-27 12:07:41.710:
>   E/(28528): User space API version: 17  10-27 12:07:41.710: E/(28528):
>   mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST
>   2013  10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main 10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial/com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-27 12:07:43.470:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28528): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:134)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 10-27
>   12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
>   10-27 12:07:43.470: E/AndroidRuntime(28528):  ... 11 more

Comment: Isto é o que está a causar o erro: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Sharing Fuel from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0013`

Comment: Ele está dizendo que não encontrou um recurso. Resources$NotFoundException: File Sharing Fuel from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0013

Comment: Como posso saber qual é este recurso ou resource que está faltando?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na linha 94 da sua classe `com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial.Welcome`

Comment: Olha aí, editei lá na pergunta, a partir da linha 94.

Comment: O terceiro parâmetro do `ActionBarDrawerToggle` não é uma `String`, é o `Drawable` que irá aparecer como indicador. Dá uma olhada: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html.

Comment: Ele deveria ficar assim então? mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
    mDrawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

Comment: @IsraelSousa, Não, deve ser: `new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)`. Lembrando que os dois últimos parâmetros não são o nome do seu app, são descrições para acessibilidade para os ícones de abrir e fechar.

Comment: amigo eu tive um problema parecido com meu app..  era uma imagem na minha tela de login que eu pegava do drawable....  eu so alterei de onde eu pegava essa imagem que era do drawable para o mipmap...